# Vim's Ctrl+P autocomplete for identifiers with dash '-'

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In Lispy code there can be identifiers with dash signs instead of underscores, like that:

```
(defn create-something ...)
(defn create-anything ...)
(defn create-nothing ...)
```

If type `crea^P`, Vim shows just "create" as completing result. How to make it interpret '-' as part of identifier and offer the whole identifiers  for completion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's an option just for you:

```
:set lisp
```

See `:help 'iskeyword'` and `:help 'lisp'`.

Comment: I'm using vim to edit css file. If I use the command `:set lisp`, the autoindent will fail.

Answer (score 32):

For those (like me) who ended up here more for CSS than lisp, the accepted (and correct!) answer may not be appropriate for you. Using `set lisp` also changes other things (like indentation).

A less intrusive method is to add the hyphen to your `iskeyword`, something like this:

`:set iskeyword+=\-`

See `help iskeyword` as @romainl suggested.